# Split a binary string into substrings of length n, then decode each substring in R

Tags: r, string, binary, substring

I have a binary string of length n which I wish to split into k sized substrings. Each substring is then decoded to decimal and added to a vector or a list.
Sorry if this is an obvious question but I'm very new to R
The example string should return: 01 01 01 01 01
Which should evaluate to 1 1 1 1 1

```
string <- 0101010101
n <- length(string)
k <- 2
#pseudocode
#For each substring in string:
#    decode substring to decimal
#    add substring to list/array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

It creates a small function `splitter` that takes the string (make sure that you input the string as a character and not as a number, otherwise leading zeroes are lost) and outputs the subsets.

```r
# make sure that you use characters and not numbers here
# otherwise leading zeros are lost!
string <- "0101010101"

splitter <- function(t, k = 2) {
  k <- min(k, nchar(t))
  substring(t, seq(1, nchar(t) - 1, k), seq(k, nchar(t), k))
}

splitter(string)
#> [1] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
splitter(string, k = 3)
#> [1] "010" "101" "010"
splitter(string, k = 100)
#> [1] "0101010101"


## if you want to cast the values as numeric (sure that you want to case binaries to numerics?)
## use

v <- splitter(string, k = 2)
as.numeric(v)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you are sure that you want to always get a numeric value, use this function

```r
splitter2 <- function(t, k = 2) {
  k <- min(k, nchar(t))
  v <- substring(t, seq(1, nchar(t) - 1, k), seq(k, nchar(t), k))
  as.numeric(v)
}
```

If you want to decode the binary values to int, use `strtoi(string, base = 2)`, i.e.,

```r
string <- "0101010101"
splitter3 <- function(t, k = 2) {
  k <- min(k, nchar(t))
  v <- substring(t, seq(1, nchar(t) - 1, k), seq(k, nchar(t), k))
  strtoi(v, base = 2)
}

splitter3(string, k = 2)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 1
splitter3(string, k = 3)
#> [1] 2 5 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Feel free to comment or edit the question/answer to reflect your edits!